# A graph-indexed family of subdirect products

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, products

I've been noodling around with a family of subdirect products recently, and it seems elementary enough that I suspect there might be something written about them already. Here is the idea.

Let $\Gamma$ be a simple graph on the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and let $G$ be a group. We will define a subgroup of $G^n$. For each $g \in G$ and $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ we define $g_i$ to be the element of $G^n$ with a $g$ in position $i$, and also in every position $j$ such that $j$ is adjacent to $i$. Then we define $G^\Gamma$ to be the subgroup of $G^n$ generated by all $g_i$.

For example, suppose that $\Gamma$ is a path of length 2, with edges connecting 1 to 2 and 2 to 3. Then $G^\Gamma$ is generated by elements of the form $(g, g, 1), (g, g, g)$, and $(1, g, g)$. It's not hard to show that in this case we get all of $G^3$.

For another simple example, if $\Gamma$ is a complete graph, then $G^\Gamma$ is the diagonal subgroup of $G^n$.

Has anyone seen this family of subdirect products before?

Comment: I haven't seen this before, but it looks interesting. It's hard to say much in full generality, but maybe in some cases with $\Gamma$ or $G$ restricted more can be said?

Here is an example small observation:  Consider the natural projection $\pi$ from $G^n$ to $G^{ab}$, the abelianisation of $G$. (First pass to $(G^{ab})^n$, then take the product of all the entries.)

Now, note that if some $k$ divides $\mathrm{deg}(v)+1$ for every vertex $v$ of $\Gamma$, then $\pi(G^\Gamma)$ is contained in the subgroup of $G^{ab}$ generated by $k$th powers.

Comment: In particular, if $k$ is not coprime to $G^{ab}$, then $G^{\Gamma}$ will be a proper subgroup of $G^n$. For example, if $G$ is a symmetric group and all the valencies are odd, then $G^{\Gamma}$ will have even index in $G^n$.

Comment: Trying to solve the problem when the graph is a tree and/or the group is $\mathbb Z$ might be a suitably unambitious start.

Comment: I think over $\mathbb{Z}$, this is equivalent to computing the Smith Normal form of $I+A$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix, no? (Of course that could still be interesting.)

Comment: Also, I think $\mathbb{Z}^\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}^n$ if and only if $G^\Gamma=G^n$ for every group $G$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but perhaps an interesting observation.

Let $G$ be a group and let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with integer entries.

For every row $R$ of $A$ and $g\in G$, let $g^R$ be the element of $G^n$ such that the entry in the $i$th position is $g^{R_i}$.

(So for example, $g^{[1,0,2,-1]}=(g,1,g^2,g^{-1})$.)

Now, let $G^A=\langle g^R\rangle\leq G^n$, where $g^R$ runs over every row $R$ and every $g\in G$.

(Note that $G^A$ generalises $G^\Gamma$, just take $A$ to be the adjacency matrix of $A$ plus the identity matrix.)

Now, we have the following observations:

- Applying invertible **row** operations (over the integers) to $A$ does **not** affect $G^A$. (Permuting rows or multiplying a row by $-1$ doesn't change the generating set, adding a row to another does change the generating set but not the generated group, because $g^{R+S}=g^Rg^S$.)
- Permuting **columns** or multiplying a **column** by $-1$ does change $G^A$, but **not** its isomorphism type.
- Adding a **column** to another **can** change the isomorphism type of $G^A$.

The last one is unfortunate, because otherwise, we could just reduce $A$ to Smith normal form and this would give us the isomorphism type of $G^A$.

Still, this is still helpful in simplifying the problem and can solve it in some cases.

For example, let $\Gamma$ be a path graph on $n$ vertices (so of length $n-1$) and $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $\Gamma$ plus the identity matrix. One can check that, if $n\not\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then $A$ can be reduced to the identity matrix using just the operations allowed above (without adding a column to another), and so in that case $G^\Gamma=G^n$.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments! With a colleague, we had found a couple of the things you've mentioned, and the others are new to us. In any case, I think there are some interesting things to figure out, and it looks hopeful that we won't be retreading old ground.

Comment: Glad this was helpful. It is indeed an interesting problem, although now that I've worked on it a bit, it seems it's too hard in full generality, but I'm such lots can be said in many cases. Keep us posted if you find anything interesting!